# bashの先頭半角置換の正しい書き方

Tags: bash, 正規表現, sed

```
 #!/bin/bash
  fuga=" string"
  
  
  echo ${fuga} | sed -e 's|^\s||'
```

出力

```
tring
```

これはどんな使用ですか？環境依存でしょうか？

Comment: sed のシングルクォートをダブルクォートに変えるとどうなりますか？

Comment: GNU sed コマンドでは `\s` が空白文字類を示す正規表現として扱われますが(`sed` コマンドのスイッチオプション次第で変わります)、基本正規表現(`BRE`)や拡張正規表現(`ERE`)にのみ対応している sed コマンドでは `s` という文字そのものにマッチすることになります。 その場合は、`[[:space:]]` を使います。`echo ${fuga} | sed -e 's|^[[:space:]]||'` もっとも、記載されているスクリプトの処理は一体何を目的にしているのか不明ですが………

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。”にしてもtring　になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。タイピングの練習をする際に、ターミナルから気軽にしたいと思いました。下記のURLを改造して使っていたのですが、bashを勉強したので、少し改修しようかなと思っています。:space:等を検索してみたいのですが、これらの名称など教えて欲しいです。よろしくお願いします。https://qiita.com/Yuki_Yamashina/items/a9edcdfc500747d5081a

Comment: @たくまいわき  「POSIX文字クラス」と呼ばれています。BRE や ERE については [Regex cheatsheet](https://remram44.github.io/regex-cheatsheet/regex.html) が参考になります。

Comment: ちなみにですが、bash には parameter expansion という機能があります。それを使うと、`echo "${fuga# }"` とすることもできます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！調べてみます！！！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## シェルの挙動

シェルは与えられたコマンドライン文字列に対して変数展開 (variable expansion)、ワード分割 (word splitting)、パス名展開 (pathname expasion) などを実行し、その結果をコマンドとして実行します。

`echo ${fuga}` がどのように解釈されるかというと:

1. 変数展開が実行され `echo  string` と解釈される
   (`echo` と `string` の間に    (スペース 2 つ))
2. ワード分割により空白文字 (1 文字以上のスペースやタブなど) で分割され `echo` と `string` の 2 要素として解釈される。
3. `echo` コマンドにコマンドライン引数 1 つ `string` を指定して実行する。
4. `echo` コマンドの実行により `string` が出力される。

このようにワード分割の過程で `${fuga}` の先頭にあったスペースが失われたものが `echo` に渡され、結果 `sed` には `string` だけが渡されます。

コマンドライン中のスペースなどをワード分割の対象外にするには `\` (バックスラッシュ) でエスケープしたり `"` (ダブルクォート) か `'` (シングルクォート) で括ってエスケープする必要があります。変数に含まれるスペースなどのワード分割を防ぐにはダブルクォートで括って変数展開する必要があります。

## sed の違いによる正規表現の違い

`sed` が対応する正規表現は「BRE」(basic regular expressions、基本正規表現) であって「ERE」(extended regular expressions、拡張正規表現) ではありません。よって正規表現 `\s` はBRE としては `s` と等価であり、これは `s` にだけマッチします。

しかし GNU sed などの特殊な sed は BRE ではなく ERE 的な BRE として解釈する機能が実装されており、正規表現 `\s` は「空白文字」にマッチします。(GNU sed は `--regexp-extended` オプションを指定することにより ERE が利用できるのに、何故こんな余計な機能を設けたのかは理解に苦しむところ)

よって sed の実装に依存しない (移植性 (portability) を考慮した) sed スクリプトを書くには GNU sed などの特殊な実装を考慮した BRE を記述する必要があります。

## 結局どうすればいいの?

「`${fuga}` に含まれるスペースなどを維持する」、「sed で先頭の 1 文字以上のスペースを削除する」(移植性を考慮する) でよければ、スクリプトは次のようになります。

```sh
#!/bin/bash
fuga=" string"
  
echo "${fuga}" | sed -e 's|^ *||'
```